# Laravel - should send notification method

Tags: laravel, notifications

I have this configuration where the user can set which notification it wants to receive, I don't want to do an If on every method that I call `notify`.

I'd like to know if is there a method inside my notification class that I can do this validation, or how could I do that.

I thought about a solution, but it seens durty, I could validate inside `via` and just return an empty array if the user setted to not receive

And I also find out a method inside `Illuminate\Notifications\NotificationSender` called `shouldSendNotification` but I don't know how I could overwrite it, or even if it is using this class, cause it seens to be only for queue

OBS: Laravel 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`via` would previously have been the best place for this, but Laravel now supports `shouldSend` on the notification for exactly this behaviour.

```php
/**
 * Determine if the notification should be sent.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $notifiable
 * @param  string  $channel
 * @return bool|null
 */
public function shouldSend($notifiable, $channel)
{
    if ($user->isUnsubscribed()) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the easiest way is to define a wrapper method in your `User` model and use it instead of `notify` like this:

```
public function _notify($notification)
{
    if ($this->notify_condition) {
        $this->notify($notification);
    }
}
```

now you use `_notify` instead of `notify`